# How Can I calculate Read Replica lag in RDS postgres?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, database-replication, read-replication, postgres-14

We have stood up the read replica, now I want to run it for a week and then calculate the lag for a week.

Is there any easy way to find out how I can calculate the avg lag for whole week?
Or during particular time
how to measure update latency in the read replica ?